# How would you make this actually show the image instead of text?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, google-chrome, replace

I am trying to make a Chrome extension that replaces the word "Trump" with a picture of Trump but the pages display this html code:

```
<img src=\"https://yt3.ggpht.com/-oIA5414kAtc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/QpC5YjQBox8/s48-c-k-no/photo.jpg" height=\"30\" width=\"30\" />
```

instead of the picture.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
        var node = element.childNodes[j];

        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            var text = node.nodeValue;
            //document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/trump/gi, '<img src=\"https://yt3.ggpht.com/-oIA5414kAtc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/QpC5YjQBox8/s48-c-k-no/photo.jpg" height=\"30\" width=\"30\" />');
            var replacedText = text.replace(/trump/gi, '<img src=\"https://yt3.ggpht.com/-oIA5414kAtc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/QpC5YjQBox8/s48-c-k-no/photo.jpg" height=\"30\" width=\"30\" />');

            if (replacedText !== text) {
                element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(replacedText), node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got it to work but with this code (the comment in the above code), it lags up the browser significantly occasionally (or sometimes crash the page):

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/trump/gi, '<img src=\"https://yt3.ggpht.com/-oIA5414kAtc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/QpC5YjQBox8/s48-c-k-no/photo.jpg" height=\"30\" width=\"30\" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but instead of replacing the element with a a text node, can you replace it with an image element?

```
// Replace
document.createTextNode(replacedText)

// With
var img = new Image()
img.width = 30;
img.height = 30;
img.src = "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-oIA5414kAtc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/QpC5YjQBox8/s48-c-k-no/photo.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = node.nodeValue;
```

Would split text on `trump`, then create new text nodes and in between the image nodes. Little more work, but way cleaner.

**Pseudocode:**

```
var s = node.split('trump')
if s.length > 1 {
// replace node with text, img, text, img, ...
var p = node.parentElement
p.insertBefore(text1,node)
p.insertBefore(img1,node)
p.insertBefore(text2,node)
p.insertBefore(img2,node)
..
p.removeChild(node)
```

Just replacing innerHTML will escape the string as you have realized already.

Also, use `Node.TEXT_NODE` instead of `3!`

Comment: this will also match elefantrumpsteak, so if you don't want this, you have to split by whitespace and then compare the strings to 'trump'.

Comment: This works but if ' trump ' is in the same node twice or more, it either shows only one of them or none at all. I think it is because the node is being removed but I am not sure how to solve this. If I do not remove it, it crashes the page (probably infinite loop).

Comment: maybe your double loop? you could try placing your texts in a <span class="trumpable"> and then iterate only over those: [].forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('span.trumpable'), 
  function(el) { code });